# Angular JS bootstrapping app

Tags: javascript, django, internet-explorer, angularjs

Hi I have a problem with bootstrapping Angular JS.

This is my HTML doc in django templating

```
<html>
 ...
<body>
 .... at the end ....
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20121008/json2.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/transition.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/collapse.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/accordion.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/tabs.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/dialog.js' %}"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/modal.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/alert.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/validated.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui/fb.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/app/base.js' %}"></script>


<script>
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
 try{      angular.bootstrap(document, ['app.base']);

 }catch(e){alert(e)}
});
</script>
```

(I know there are many UI scripts... but that's not the point)

**Edited**
i think the problem is that I am running django's dev server which doesn't handle concurrent requests quite well. Apparently, it would sometimes drop connections, thereby causing the browser not to load files (random). This problem has been observed in Chrome as well as other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when Angular throws a "no module" error, it means that there is an error in that module. It has nothing to do with the order they're loaded. I'd run a jsLint on the file and see if it compiles.

Do you need to bootstrap manually? If you're only loading one app you can attach an ng-app directive to any HTML element. I'm not sure you can use the try-catch like that with bootstrapping. What I do is something like this:

```
$.when(angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('my-div'), ['my-app']))
    .done(function() {
        console.log("my-app has been bootstrapped to my-div");
    });
```

Comment: Auto bootstrapping (and all bootstrapping) is failing because the ui.accordion module is doing something that IE8 doesn't like. Can you load it without the ui.accordion module?